Help with a differential equation
I am trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$
(x - 1) x f''(x) + (2 x - 1) f'(x) + \alpha^2 x^2 f(x) =0,
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x >0$.
I have already tried a few approaches, such as solving it in terms of a generalized hypergeometric function, using the Meijer G-function, and trying various substitutions.
Does someone have an idea on how to solve this equation?
Edits:

I am particularly interested in a solution $f$ that asymptotes to $0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

As md2perpe mentioned in the comments, we have that $\frac{d}{dx}((x-1)x) = 2x - 1$, which motivates to rewrite the equation as:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Big[ (x-1)x f'(x) \Big] + \alpha^2 x^2 f(x) = 0.
$$
This further motivates a substitution that would eliminate the prefactor of $f'(x)$, which is given by $t = \log\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right) - i \pi$ (I subtracted $i \pi$ here so that $t \in \mathbb{R}$ for $x > 1$). Performing this substitution and performing some manipulations then results in
$$
16 e^t \sinh\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^4 f''(t) + \alpha^2 f(t) = 0.
$$
While this shape is already somewhat simpler, it does not seem to have a trivial solution.



I notice that $\frac{d}{dx}((x-1)x) = 2x-1$. That is probably useful.

What about a series solution ? It shows polynomials terms + a polynomial multiplied by $\log(x)$. May be this explains the difficulty. By the way, what are the conditions ? This is an important point. Please, precise what they are.

@md2perpe: Thank you for pointing this out. This indeed helps to simplify the equation and eliminates the first derivative of f at the cost of introducing exponential terms. I will edit my post to also include this perhaps simpler version of the differential equation.

@ClaudeLeibovici: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am interested in the solution over the entire domain of $x$. I also prepared a series expansion for this differential equation for $x \rightarrow \infty$, but ideally, I would like a solution that is also valid around $x \sim 1$. I will adjust my post to include the conditions that I am interested in.

$$f! \left(x\right)=c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{i \alpha  x}\cdot \mathrm{HeunC}! \left(2 ,i \alpha ,0,0,\alpha^{2},0,x\right)+c_{2} {\mathrm e}^{i \alpha x}\cdot \mathrm{HeunC}! \left(2 ,i \alpha ,0,0,\alpha^{2},0,x\right)\cdot \left(\int\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-2 ,i \alpha  x}}{\left(x-1\right) x \mathrm{HeunC}! \left(2 ,i \alpha ,0,0,\alpha^{2},0,x\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
$\mathrm{HeunC}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\eta,z)$ is the Heun confluent function.

@gpmath: Thank you for pointing me toward the HeunC function! When I try to evaluate this function in Mathematica, I get $\infty$ for $\alpha \neq 0$. I assume that the syntax in your comment differs from the one Mathematica uses. Do you have a reference that explains the syntax for your case?

See Maple worksheet MSE_Q5017706

@gpmath: Amazing! Thank you so much for preparing this worksheet for me! Do you want to post this result as an answer? I would then mark my question as completed.
